# libfingersense.so was not loaded E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting this error in logcat while loading foodlist from menu list from firebase database.
here is the file  kindly help me. I am running the app in android nougat apk 24.

```
public class FoodList extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference foodList;
String categoryId;

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food,FoodViewHolder> adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_list);

    database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    foodList=database.getReference("Food");
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_food);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    if(getIntent()!=null) {
        categoryId = getIntent().getStringExtra("CategoryId");

        if(categoryId != null&& !categoryId.isEmpty()) {

                loadListFood(categoryId);

            }
    }

}

private void loadListFood(String categoryId) {
    adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder>(Food.class,
            R.layout.food_item,FoodViewHolder.class,
            foodList.orderByChild("MenuId").equalTo(categoryId)) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(FoodViewHolder viewHolder, Food model, int position) {
            viewHolder.food_name.setText(model.getName());
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage()).into(viewHolder.food_image);

            final Food local=model;
            viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onclick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                    Toast.makeText(FoodList.this, ""+local.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

}

Comment: It's only a warning, but if you're concerned about it, you can first set an empty adapter.

Comment: Are you sure all conditions that are apart of your if statement are true? Please reponde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo Actually i want to load a foodlist stored in firebase. The menu list is working fine but when i click the menu item it doesnot display the foodlist infact it displays a white blanck screen what should i do?

Comment: Please add your database structure and also tell us how is your `foodList` reference defined.